# What are the uses of a http proxy?

Tags: http, https, proxy, http-proxy

I googled around and read articles about http-proxy, and even watched youtube videos but i'm still not quite clear on how http-proxy works and its uses, dumb me.

I get the gist of it that it is an intermediary between the client and the server, so when the client sends a request it goes through the http proxy and when the server responds it goes through the proxy too.

Since the server receives requests from the proxy instead of the client itself, does it mean the client is anonymous? Hence using a http-proxy provides security, and allows access to restricted websites?

I hear many different pros of http-proxy such as caching internet access control and sharing internet connections on a LAN but i have no idea how any of those work or come about.

Comment: Surely all the "many different pros" that you hear about are "uses of an http proxy"?

Comment: Yes but im unsure of how they work

Comment: That isn't what you asked. Please consider more carefully what your question actually is. If you want to know "how does a http proxy help share internet access on a LAN" than ask that as a direct question. I would also like to point out that this question is slightly off topic for stack overflow because we're here to talk specifically about programming topics - if your post doesn't include code or algorithm, or an error message in relation to some software you're writing, it's probably off topic.I'd recommend you post more general questions about proxies and how to configure them on superuser

Answer (score 1):

A proxy is a combined server and client that sits between you (the end user) and the server you actually want to use. The proxy can vary in intelligence from relatively dumb (just passes on requests and passes back responses ) to smart (caches previous responses and responds on behalf of the server, routes requests to different places depending on content, source or destination, adds functionality such as authentication or security not supported by the server). When it is talking to you (the end her) it is behaving as a server. When it talks to the actual server it is behaving as a client. It receives your request, understands it, makes its own request, receives and understands the response and then sends you the response it got.

The key thing with a proxy is that often you don't know it's there; you don't configure to use it directly. It is inserted into the pipeline between you and the server and performs its function relatively autonomously.

Does a proxy make you anonymous? To the server, yes(maybe), but not to the proxy! The proxy knows who you are and has logged it. If it is operated by the same person who owns the server then you're not anonymous to that person

Does a proxy make you secure and provide access to restricted websites? Not necessarily. The proxy does whatever it's administrator tells it to do, and it had a specific job. If that job is to provide extra security or access to a restricted section of network then sure, it does those things.

If a real world metaphor would help, a proxy is like you being an events manager and you're booking a hugely popular music artist for your concert, but you have to go via their agent; you can't pick up the phone and talk to Taylor Swift directly, and it's this way for a variety of reasons.

As to the uses of a proxy; I mentioned a few above but it's by no means an exhaustive list. The possible uses one can put a proxy to are about as unlimited as what one can put a typical server-client relationship to. The usual uses surround making resource use more efficient, and holding data nearer to where it will be (re)used, spreading load across multiple servers, providing a single point of control for access or adding something that the server does not or cannot support, making connections appear to come from a different place and/or logging and monitoring activity and implementing limits

Comment: Thank you so much! What software do you recommend to set up a http-proxy server to demonstrate its uses? Is squid proxy good?

Comment: Asking for recommendations of software is definitely off topic for the site I'm afraid - if you're interested to look at how proxying works in general then anything that works and is simple to set up will do just fine. As an example of a proxy that developers use, Fiddler is popular; it helps us see what data our browser is sending to the server and what the response is, which can be vital when debugging our programs. Most of fiddler's power comes from its great range of inspectors so we can look at the request and response in different ways. It's a supplement to your browser's dev tools